# How to add soft goods items in ATG control center(acc)?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I want to know how to add soft goods item in Acc like ("E-books","Songs","Videos") and i want add these items into shopping cart, Here i listed my query below..

1.)Add soft goods items("E-books","Songs","Videos") in ACC,
2.)And i want to add these items to my Shopping cart,
3.)And i want to place the order(with these items),when placing the order i have to deliver the items through email address..

```
                I gone through oracle docs but they mentioned only for hard goods items
```

so give me only any right solution..

Please help me out,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ACC is not the right tool for this.  I would recommend that you look at the ATG CSC (known as CSR in older versions of ATG).

The Oracle documentation found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Service.10-2/ATGCommerceServiceCenterUserGuide/ATGCommerceServiceCenterUserGuide.pdf) should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

use the bcc to add the soft good items, it can be done by acc but the bcc is the right way. When u add a item in bcc u have to aprove it by passing for some stages and it gonna to production. When u pass for all this stages and it gonna to production u can acess this itens and put it on your shopcart. To e-mail the order u can use Scenarios from acc, u gonna create one scenario who gonna send a e-mail when a order is placed.

Thanks